# Decompose xml node into other nodes using xslt

Tags: xml, svg, xslt

I am trying to replace a node with other nodes, using the attributes of the original node and I am not able to find a way.

The specific node I need to replace is feDropShadow, and I need to create new nodes that use all the attributes of that node.

`<feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0" stdDeviation="1.5 1.5" flood-color="rgb(0,0,0)" flood-opacity="0.8"/>`

TO:

```
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1.5 1.5"/>
<feOffset dx="0" dy="0" result="offsetblur"/>
<feFlood flood-color="rgb(0,0,0)" flood-opacity="0.8"/>
<feComposite in="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
<feMerge>
    <feMergeNode/>
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
</feMerge>
```

This is the original xml:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="2175" height="1078" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;user-select:none">
    <rect width="2175" height="1078" x="0" y="0" id="0" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="0"/>
    <g>
        <path d="M1619.864 616.3818A539 539 0 0 1 1626.5 700.7L1584.5 700.7A497 497 0 0 0 1578.3811 622.9521Z" fill="#008000" filter="url(#zr0-s0)"/>
        <path d="M1502.8066 357.1285A539 539 0 0 1 1619.864 616.3818L1578.3811 622.9521A497 497 0 0 0 1470.4451 383.9003Z" fill="#68FF72" filter="url(#zr0-s0)"/>
        <path d="M548.5 700.7A539 539 0 0 1 1502.8066 357.1285L1470.4451 383.9003A497 497 0 0 0 590.5 700.7Z" fill="#FF0000" filter="url(#zr0-s0)"/>
        <path d="M590.5 700.7L591.5 700.7" fill="none" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="0"/>
        <text dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="start" style="font-size:10px;font-family:Lato;" x="509.5" y="700.7000000000002" fill="#666">0</text>
    </g>
    <defs>
        <filter id="zr0-s0" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%">
            <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0" stdDeviation="1.5 1.5" flood-color="rgb(0,0,0)" flood-opacity="0.8"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

This is the output I would need:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="2175" height="1078" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;user-select:none">
    <rect width="2175" height="1078" x="0" y="0" id="0" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="0"/>
    <g>
        <path d="M1619.864 616.3818A539 539 0 0 1 1626.5 700.7L1584.5 700.7A497 497 0 0 0 1578.3811 622.9521Z" fill="#008000" filter="url(#zr0-s0)"/>
        <path d="M1502.8066 357.1285A539 539 0 0 1 1619.864 616.3818L1578.3811 622.9521A497 497 0 0 0 1470.4451 383.9003Z" fill="#68FF72" filter="url(#zr0-s0)"/>
        <path d="M548.5 700.7A539 539 0 0 1 1502.8066 357.1285L1470.4451 383.9003A497 497 0 0 0 590.5 700.7Z" fill="#FF0000" filter="url(#zr0-s0)"/>
        <path d="M590.5 700.7L591.5 700.7" fill="none" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="0"/>
        <text dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="start" style="font-size:10px;font-family:Lato;" x="509.5" y="700.7000000000002" fill="#666">0</text>
    </g>
    <defs>
        <filter id="zr0-s0" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1.5 1.5"/>
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="0" result="offsetblur"/>
            <feFlood flood-color="rgb(0,0,0)" flood-opacity="0.8"/>
            <feComposite in="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

And this is my attempt with xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="feDropShadow">

        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha">
            <xsl:attribute name="stdDeviation">
                <xsl:value-of select="@stdDeviation"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </feGaussianBlur>
        
        <feOffset result="offsetblur">
            <xsl:attribute name="dx">
                <xsl:value-of select="@dx"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="dy">
                <xsl:value-of select="@dy"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </feOffset>
        
        <feFlood>
            <xsl:attribute name="flood-color">
                <xsl:value-of select="@flood-color"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="flood-opacity">
                <xsl:value-of select="@flood-opacity"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </feFlood>
        
        <feComposite in="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode/>
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </feMerge>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This xslt is not producing any changes to the original xml.

Comment: Read up on XML namespaces and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: Note that the elements created by your stylesheet need also to be placed in the SVG namespace.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: Solved, the problem was the namespace. Thanks.